# Obtener objeto generator usando exec()

Tags: python

Estoy intentando obtener un objeto generator con la función `exec()`:

```
stringDado = "(x, y) for x in {'A','B','C'} for y in {'A','B','C'} if x != y"
exec('dominio = [' + stringDado + ']')
```

Sin embargo, con esto obtengo el resultado, es decir, la combinatoria de tuplas. Yo lo que quiero es el objeto generator que da lugar a eso.

Comment: Te faltaría meterlo entre [], () o {} según lo que quieras conseguir. Algo así: `"[(x, y) for x in {'A','B','C'} for y in {'A','B','C'} if x != y]"`

Comment: No sé si te servirá de algo, ya que no sé qué quieres conseguir, pero tu código hace lo mismo que este: `print(list(permutations('ABC', 2)))` (habiendo importado previamente `from itertools import permutations`. No sé si tienes la posibilidad de que el usuario ingrese únicamente `ABC` con un `input()`, en ese caso también podrías hacerlo de otras formas.

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace la idea es que el usuario de varios conjuntos de variables strings y que se realice permutaciones. Sin embargo, no hay un numero definido de cuantos conjuntos puede introducir. También tendría que recibir distintas condiciones, es decir, puede que se quiera que x != y pero también que 'A' y 'B' no coincidan en la misma tupla. Por eso he decidido que introduzca toda la línea de código, porque puede que la tupla tenga más elementos, diferentes y con diferentes condiciones. Si se te ocurre alguna manera de recibirlos sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: Mirate el módulo `itertools`, además de `permutations` tienes otras opciones que te podían valer (`product`, `combinations`, etc) da igual que sean varios conjuntos, también te lo puede hacer. En cuanto a las condiciones, también podrías hacerlo si tienes claro que condiciones se pueden presentar, pero es demasiado amplio para especular.

Comment: La sentencia es sintácticamente invalida, no importa que lo corras con `exec` o directamente desde el interprete, no funciona, ciertamente lo que has agregado a tu pregunta lo corrige, ¿Se puede ejecutar de otra forma? Si esperas que el usuario cargue código python y evaluarlo, y que eso sea seguro,  no hay muchas alternativas, `literal_eval` ciertamente es un poco mas segura, pero no infalible tal como se menciona en la documentación: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval